# Fsharp - How do i convert a sequence to ParallelQuery?

Tags: f#, parallel-processing

I have a sequence of objects that i am processing using ParallelEnumerable.Aggregate()
However the source for the Aggregate function needs to be a ParallelQuery.

How do I cast a sequence to ParallelQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [AsParallel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd413602.aspx)

```
open System.Linq

let (inputSeq: seq<int>) = [1;2;3]
let parallel = inputSeq.AsParallel()
```

Answer (score 2):

`PSeq` in PowerPack provides an F#-friendly interface for parallel queries. It [defines an `ofSeq` function](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/71313#1233342) but, for whatever reason, it isn't public.

You could recreate it as a module extension.